# Can a .Net application compiled with an older assembly's Interface create objects with a newer version?

Tags: .net, .net-assembly

I have a 3rd-party application that I am using with my C# desktop code.  I use several of the interfaces in a library provided by the manufacturer. The library consists of many DLLs of which I access one for the interfaces. 
I have found that when they release a new version of the application I have a couple of problems.

The install code copied the DLL I was referencing on my development machine to the projects bin folder. I fixed that by temporarily adding the path to the DLL before implementing a concreate instance of the interface and not copying it during the build.

The problem now is I can’t create their object.  The error is:

```
Unable to cast object of type ‘ThirdPartyObject’ to type ‘IThirdPartyObject’.
```

I think this is because my source code is referencing a different version of the DLL. When the program runs, it knows it’s not the same as it was compiled against. This is even though the signatures are the same between versions and the public key tokens are the same.

I’ve visually compared the signatures of the interfaces I use in the VS Object Explorer and they match.

I tried going the other way by copying the newer DLL into a folder on my machine and referencing that one. After compiling I get the casting error on my computer and it works on the test computer.

I thought this would work otherwise how could a Binding Redirect work?

I thought about manually loading the assembly, but then how do I access the methods?  Looking at the lookup methods it seems that it isn’t easy. Would I have to create my own Interface and adapter to map theirs to mine so I do the look up once?

Comment: Sure, different version is the standard cause.  The identity of the .NET type is not just the namespace + type name (members of the type play no role), it also includes the fully specified assembly name.  [AssemblyVersion] is crucial.  Recompiling with the updated reference assembly is necessary.  It won't hurt to let the supplier know that they ought to consider stabilizing their interfaces, too easy to overlook and (usually) too easy to fix.

Comment: So we have to recompile every time a bug fix version is released?
The full name of the original:
    SDK.NET.Interface, Version17.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
The new version:
    SDK.NET.Interface, Version17.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
I would think the version should change to reflect the bug fixes.

Comment: A BindingRedirect in your .config file can usually paper over such a minor difference.  It is however crucial that you deploy their updated assembly.

Comment: Can I use the binding redirect to tell it that no mater what version of assembly it finds (older or newer) to consider it the one I used in compilation? I understand if they break something all bets are off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use a BindingRedirect in the main application's App.Config that reflected the version of the assembly that I had referenced when I compiled the program.

I had tried placing it in the App.Config of the project that referenced the target assembly, but that had no noticeable effect. Moving the block of XML to the main executable App.Config made it work.

```
<configuration>
  <startup> 
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
  </startup>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="SDK.NET.Interface"
                          publicKeyToken="865eaf3445b2ea56"
                          culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-65535.65535.65535.65535"
                         newVersion="17.1.1.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

A side note. Because the the referenced dll was not referenced in the main executable I had to manually add it to setup files list for the installer. In the long run this module will be optional and may not need this dependency so I didn't want to add it to the main project's references.

Answer (score 0):

> Can a .Net application compiled with an older assembly's Interface create objects with a newer version?

If the third party company split out the assemblies, one to hold the interfaces and the other to hold the code, one could do what you want.

But because they don't, the interface is tagged with that specific version and hence you get the casting error where the names/namespace are the same.

> The install code copied the DLL I was referencing on my development machine to the projects bin folder.

Installing to different locations won't help, nor loading. You have already mentioned creating a work around which is a project in itself.

The only option is to either update the code to the new version, or not update at all.